# Quelles sont les nuances entre « accorder du temps », « accorder de votre temps », « offrir du temps » et « offrir de votre temps »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

Contexte.

Dans le sens de « passer du temps avec quelqu’un dans le but de l’aider alors que l’obligation n’y est pas »

Je vous remercie de m’avoir accordé du temps/de votre temps.

Je vous remercie de m’avoir offert du temps/de votre temps.

Je vous remercie de m’avoir donné du temps/de votre temps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I** 1/ « Offrir du/son temps » ne se disait pas ou peu, mais depuis 1980 cela se dit de plus en plus ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=19&smoothing=3&content=offrir+son+temps%2Coffrir+du+temps&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coffrir%20son%20temps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coffrir%20du%20temps%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Coffrir%20son%20temps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coffrir%20du%20temps%3B%2Cc0)). C'est une expression associée au bénévolat ([réf.](https://www.mghfoundation.com/fr/impliquez-vous/offrir-votre-temps/)).

Cette [réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=EoL0CfHkLx8C&pg=PT334&dq=%22offrir+son+temps%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYw9XCgdrrAhXlx4UKHUNJAiUQ6AEwAXoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22offrir%20son%20temps%22&f=false) (roman) confirme le sens qui est donné à cette expression.

- Son mari la taquinait un peu, mais les œuvres de charité étaient une affaire de femme et son épouse semblait plus heureuse d'offrir son temps aux misérables que de côtoyer les mieux nantis.

2/ On peut aussi utiliser ces expressions dans le contexte beaucoup moins formel du temps passé, sur la base d'une amitié personnelle, au service de quelqu'un ou tout simplement avec quelqu'un.

**II** 1/ « donner du/son temps » est synonyme d'« offrir son/du temps (1/), (2/) » dans le sens que l'on prête à cette expression dans le contexte du bénévolat ou le contexte de l'amitié personnelle évoqué ci-dessus.

2/ Cette expression peut avoir un tout autre sens; elle peut vouloir dire « faire en sorte que quelqu'un ait du temps pour lui permettre d'accomplir quelque chose ou pour lui donner un delai plus grand ».

3/ Il y a aussi un sens figuré; selon ce sens, « donner son temps à l"étude » signifie simplement  « se consacrer à l'étude ».

4/ « donner de son temps », qui signifie « donner une partie de son temps » est plus ou moins synonyme de « donner son temps ».

On dira par exemple « Pour réussir dans cette sorte d'entreprise, il faut donner **de** son temps. ». On ne dira pas, cependant,

- « …, il faut donner son temps. ».

Ceci montre que les deux formes verbales ne sont pas totalement équivalentes. Avec la préposition « de » en plus le verbe a une signification qui n'est plus aussi simple; il s'agit alors d'une consécration plus ou moins passionnée de son temps.

**III** « Accorder » n'a pas de sens particulier dans le domaine du bénévolat.
1/ « Accorder/du temps » est synonyme de « donner du temps (**II** 2/) » ; c'est le sens le plus courant.
2/  On trouve aussi le sens « **I** (2/) ».

- Mais tu as un peu de temps à m'accorder, du temps pour fumer une cigarette et discuter un peu ? » Une fois de plus sa question ressemblait plus à une affirmation ou à une invitation à le contredire.  ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=WvFooaU0uLYC&pg=PT104&dq=%22accorder+du+temps%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSlMisi9rrAhUG8BQKHd9GBOsQ6AEwX3oECBYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22accorder%20du%20temps%22&f=false))

**IV** 1/ « Accorder son temps à quelqu'un » ne se dit que dans le sens « **III** 1/ »